Ubuntu Landscape -Ubuntu Pro
This is Ahmed from Ntis procurement department, we would like to order the below

Ubuntu Landscape, self-hosted, Qty = 2.
Ubuntu Pro, Qty = 4.

So please advise, the Ubuntu Landscape, self-hosted will be included when we purchase the Ubuntu Pro?
Or, we have to purchase it separately?

You've asked this on a user-support site; the items you mention are offered by Canonical and not Stack Exchange; so why ask here?  This site is supported by the Ubuntu community, and not affiliated with Canonical.  Refer to the web sites (eg. https://ubuntu.com/landscape for Landscape) as the contact us will direct your query to Canonical, and not end-users such as this site. There is also the Ubuntu Pro FAQ (on a Ubuntu/Canonical site) too that maybe helpful - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-pro-faq/34042
